# Material UI - Facing an issue that drop down options are coming below the modal window footer

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I am using material ui and react select .  I am facing an issue that my drop-drown options are showing below the modal window.

Here is the codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-torvalds-6m65i)

[image: dropdown option are coming below the modal footer]

I tried z-index and change the position value to absolute but did not get the success. Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because of *overflow-y* rule in two places: the dialog paper, and the dialog content.
simply use material-ui styling to override this rules:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paperFullWidth: {
    overflowY: 'visible'
  },
  dialogContentRoot: {
    overflowY: 'visible'
  }
});
```

And than apply this classes to your component:

```
const classes = useStyles();
   ...
<Dialog
        ...
        fullWidth={true}
        classes={{
          paperFullWidth: classes.paperFullWidth
        }}
      >
  ...
 <DialogContent
        classes={{
          root: classes.dialogContentRoot
        }}
```

You can refer this [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-forest-kosj7?fontsize=14)